# Is there a limit on angular $timeout duration?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout

I'm calling two $timeout functions, one with a delay of 1000 and one with a delay of 3000000000. The longer delay always fires immediately. Is this a limitation of the function, or a mistake on my part?

To make things even more weird, a 100000000000 doesn't necessarily cause the error as 3000000000 does

```js
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('FrameController', ['$injector', '$timeout',
  function($injector, $timeout) {
    var liveTimers = [];

    function setExpiryTime(timer, timeRemaining) {
      if (liveTimers[timer]) {
        cancel(liveTimers[timer]);
        delete liveTimers[timer];
      }
      liveTimers[timer] = $timeout(function() {
        alert(timer + " timer expired")
        console.log(timer + " expired");
        delete liveTimers[timer];
      }, timeRemaining);

    }

    setExpiryTime('first', 1000);
    setExpiryTime('second', 100000000000);
    setExpiryTime('third', 30000000000);

  }
]);

setTimeout(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('body'), ['app']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
  <div ng-controller="FrameController">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of making a timeout set for 34 days?

Comment: The timer is set by user input. This is not a typical case, but it could happen and I wanted to know what sort of restrictions I need to apply, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that 30000000000 goes beyond the int memory. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/UXkuM6lEO1xvqcN6Mre5?p=preview) is a plunker with your code, and I could go close to

```
setExpiryTime('third', 19300000000);
```

without having third timer expiring.

That is about 2^34.